# Regulations for Traveling with Tools in Mexico

Tags: international-travel, mexico, travel-tools

I am an Electrical Engineer who will be traveling to Mexico, I will be flying. I will be bringing tools into the country along with a laptop and other company property. What are the laws I should look into when bringing in tools? Would this be considered importing and should I prepare a declaration stating the value of the tools I am bringing into the country? I will be working as a control engineer through my employer. I will be bringing in 2 digital multi meters that are around $500 dollars each. Then about 60 other tools that have a price tag of around 10 to 60 dollars each.

[Link to the Custom Regulations that I am inquiring about](https://www.trade.gov/country-commercial-guides/mexico-customs-regulations)

Comment: What tools are we talking about: a $5 screw driver or a $50,000 dollar high speed digital storage oscilloscope ?

Comment: You might want to register your equipment with US customer before you go. I think [this form](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2022-May/CBP%20Form%204455.pdf) would work.

Comment: You are being paid by your employer, and not directly by anyone in Mexico, yes? It should not be considered importing if you are intending to leave with the tools, however if the tools are very expensive you might need a carnet. It's expensive and troublesome and not required unless the $$$ are large.  A large company should provide advice on how to deal with customs and immigration. You are exporting as far as some factions of the US government are concerned so you should make sure nothing that conflicts with their ideas of what is acceptable to export is with you (including documents).

Comment: The amounts you mention are not too worrisome, IMHO. Sounds like it doesn't even add up to a midrange laptop computer. Especially if they are clearly used and not new tools in factory packaging. A list of the tools with estimated current values (a $500 DMM might be worth $200 used) on company letterhead as a backup couldn't hurt, in case you're asked. This is more opinion than experience with this particular border, so I'm leaving this as a comment. As a degreed (or state licensed) Engineer you have privileged position wrt working there under the FTA, as do Mexican Engineers entering the US.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The 60 tools in the $10 to $60 will outweigh the multimeters

Comment: One of my team members ended getting stopped and they cited this law. However, none of us were stopped we each had laptops digital storage and etc. That far exceeded the cost of anything that was mentioned in the citation. These devices were well over 20,000 but they had no issues with that in fact the guy who had it passed through with no issues. The guy who was stopped had nothing of intrinsic value besides the tools. The team mate that was stopped was billed 96 dollars. I am still confused since our travel agent had all of the issues "handled" .

Comment: @DavidWisniewski I'm guessing that "team mate that was stopped" means you didn't declare when you entered Mexico?  The $96 will possibly have been a fine for not declaring items that should have been declared.  Even if your travel agent had all things "handled", you probably still had to declare everything when entering the country.